# Delete an item in a listbox with a button, in wpf MVVM

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have a problem. It seems a simple thing but it isn't that easy. I have two listboxes, with objects in it. One is full with available objects and the other is empty, and I can fill this up with drag and drop. If you fill this empty listbox, the items are also added to a list of, this is a property of another object. But now my question is how I can easily delete an object in this listbox by clicking on a button.

I tried something but it wouldn't run. 
Here is my xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableQuestions}"          
         DisplayMemberPath="Description" 
         dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" 
         dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" Margin="0,34,0,339" Background="#CDC5CBC5"
         dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}"/>

        <ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedQuestionDropList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedQuestions}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                 dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" 
                 dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" Margin="0,201,0,204" Background="#CDC5CBC5"
                 dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}"  />

 <Button Content="Delete" Height="23" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         Margin="513,322,0,0"  
         Name="button1" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding Commands}"    
         CommandParameter="Delete" />
```

here is my viewmodel:

```
// other stuff and properties..
public ICommand Commands { get; set; }

public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    return true;
}
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
}
public void Execute(Object parameter)
{
    foreach (ExaminationQuestion exaq in this.Examination.ExaminationQuestions)
    {
        if (exaq.Question.Guid == SelectedQuestionDropList.Guid)
        {
            this.Examination.ExaminationQuestions.Remove(exaq);
            SelectedQuestions.Remove(SelectedQuestionDropList);
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedQuestions");
        }
    }               
}
```

can somebody please help me out?

Comment: Please add an adequate error description. "Wouldn't run" isn't helpful.

Comment: If i click on the button, nothing happens at all.. the command isn't fired...

Comment: Do you have a proper `CommandBinding` in place?

Comment: He means, do you have a `Command="{Binding Commands}"` - a binding to the command.  Calling your command `Commands` is a very bad idea by the way.

Comment: No that is not what i meant, but i just noticed he uses `ICommand` which encapsulates the methods that should be called, with `RoutedCommands` you can bind the command to different event handlers that fit what the command should do in a specific context (`CommandBinding`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to know two things:

- First, Don't forget to bind your `ListBox` to an `ObservableCollection` rather than to a classic IList. Otherwise, if your command is actually fired and removes an item from the list, the UI wouldn't change at all
- Second, your command here is never created. Let me explain. You are binding the Delete button to your command Commands. It has a getter. However, if you call get, what will it return? Nothing, the command is null...

Here is the way I'd advise you to work: Create a generic command class (I called it RelayCommand, following a tutorial... but the name doesn't matter):

```
/// <summary>
    /// Class representing a command sent by a button in the UI, defines what to launch when the command is called
    /// </summary>
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        #region Fields

        readonly Action<object> _execute;
        readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

        #endregion // Fields

        #region Constructors

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
            : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }
        #endregion // Constructors

        #region ICommand Members

        //[DebuggerStepThrough]
        /// <summary>
        /// Defines if the current command can be executed or not
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parameter"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }

        #endregion // ICommand Members
    }
```

Then, in your ViewModel, create a property command, and define the actual getter (you don't have to use the setter, you can just forget it):

```
private RelayCommand _deleteCommand;

public ICommand DeleteCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_deleteCommand == null)
                {
                    _deleteCommand = new RelayCommand(param => DeleteItem());
                }
                return _deleteCommand;
            }
        }
```

This means that when you call your command, it will call the function `DeleteItem`

The only thing left to do is:

```
   private void DeleteItem() {
//First step: copy the actual list to a temporary one
ObservableCollection<ExaminationQuestion> tempCollection = new ObservableCollection<ExaminationQuestion>(this.Examination.ExaminationQuestions);
//Then, iterate on the temporary one:
        foreach (ExaminationQuestion exaq in tempCollection)
                {
                    if (exaq.Question.Guid == SelectedQuestionDropList.Guid)
                    {
//And remove from the real list!
                        this.Examination.ExaminationQuestions.Remove(exaq);
                        SelectedQuestions.Remove(SelectedQuestionDropList);
                        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedQuestions");
                    }
                }
    }
```

And there you go :)

Comment: thanks a lot! But now i get an error in the for each:
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

I changed everything to an observablecollection as well..

Comment: Oh, of course, you cannot remove items from a list if you are currently iterating! A stupid but efficient way to handle this problem is to create a second temporary list, to iterate in this list, and remove items from the actual list you're working with. Thus, the temporary list won't be modified, and there goes the problem as well

Comment: Oh, and by the way, as @Kieren Johnstone said in another post, it's a bad idea to call your command `Commands`. Call it, for example, as I gave you, `DeleteCommand`. When you'll have one command per button, you'll need it to be easily understandable :)

Comment: Ok, i already edited it. can you give me some code because i don't really understand your answer about that temporary list. Sorry i'm a bit newbie :)

Comment: Just edited the code with what you need. Just keep in mind that I don't think that this is the best solution... It works, and that's what we want, right? :)

Comment: Thanks, it works, but the view isn't updated, so in Examination.ExaminationQuestions the examinationquestion is deleted. But now it also have to be deleted in the view.. An idea :p

Comment: Do you implement INotifyPropertyChanged? If not, this is the reason :)