# How to delete from a list? MVVM pattern orientated

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So I've got a listview and it's itemsSource property bound to an ObservableCollection, placed on the view model. And a button the on view
How do I make it so the button deletes the item, selected on the listview, from the observableCollection?

Comment: You could use a command functionality.

Check an answer to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472071/delete-an-item-in-a-listbox-with-a-button-in-wpf-mvvm

Answer (score 5):

Just to add another way to do it:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"             
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>

<Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
```

In your ViewModel you have a property called `SelectedItem` that will be updated every time you change the selection in the `ListView`.

Now you can handle deletion in the `ViewModel` easily:

```
internal class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.DeleteCommand = new RelayCommand(() => this.Delete());
    }
    public void Delete()
    {
        this.MyList.Remove(this.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

Go [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) for further information about `RelayCommand`

Comment: There will be a bug if list contains duplicates and user selects to delete items other than the first duplicate. E.g. if user selects the last item in the list `{2, 3, 4, 5, 2}`, then the command will delete the first item.

Comment: The meaning of _Delete_ should be defined in your business case and implemented in the method `Delete`. Furthermore, delete the first occurrence is probably what you want in 80% of the cases.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do this. One way is to create a `RelayCommand` or a `DelegateCommand` with Parameter

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyDeleteCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=mylistview, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

You can go the way AlSki posted and bind the `SelectedItem` to your `ViewModel` and handle the command without parameter in your `ViewModel`

Answer (score 1):

Bind a second property to the list views selected item, and a third to a Command on the view model, that simply removes the selected from the list of items.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx